# In Angular unit testing, not hitting the angular service if return type is observable of any for string data

Tags: angular

Spyon(service,methodname).and.return(observable of('TEST'). This is method for service .This is not hitting service in debugger,but similar method with return type class object is working.Issue with string as return. Please help for this.

Answer (score 0):

you've not given us much to go on with your question. Could you please add more information?

I'm **guessing** you're using Angular in default here with jasmine as your testing framework.
However, I can attempt to guess the issue.

You are setting a `debugger` statement in your function but you are spying on that function. The spy means you **remove the function's implementation** (this means that the code inside the function is removed / not executed) so the `debugger` statement no longer exists.

To keep a function's implementation, you need to `spyon(service, 'methodName').and.callThrough()`

However, this does not allow you to return a specific value from the function.

> Consider putting the debugger statement in the test itself to allow
>   you to step through in that way.

See this for more information about spys https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction